# How do I detect if a MongoDB replica set is not initialised when using the java driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I would like to detect if a MongoDB replica set has been initialised yet or not (so I can display an error message to the user like "you forgot to initialise your replica set"). Is it possible to detect if the replica set has been initialised using the Java Mongodb driver? The closest I have found is `com.mongodb.Mongo.getReplicaSetStatus()` - but I don't think this will tell me if the set is not initialised.

Answer (score 2):

If Mongo ReplicaSet is not initilized rs.status() return error code "94"
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.yml

```
init_status=$(mongo --quiet -u ${MONGO_ADMIN_USER} -p ${MONGO_ADMIN_PASSWORD} --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "rs.status().code" admin)
if [ "${init_status}" = "94" ]; then
    echo "Mongo ReplicaSet is not initialized"
fi
```

Comment: Instead of getting response from `rs.status()` I'm getting generic error:
`MongoServerError: no replset config has been received`
and wonder if I should just try to detect this error message or there is some more universal and reliable way to handle various cases of replicaiton not being set-up

Comment: ok, using `--eval "try { rs.status().ok } catch (e) { e.code }"` works more or less as expected...

Answer (score 1):

your can directly check the condition :

```
if(rs.status()) 
{ 
    rs.remove() 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only see old answers here, but I'm surprised that nobody mentioned the `ok` property. The `rs.status()` command includes this property in both successful and failed responses. The `ok` property is set to `1` when the replica set is initialized and `0` when it is not.

Example:

```
# When Replica Set is initialized
$ mongo --quiet --port 27017 --username your-user --password your-pass --eval 'rs.status().ok'
1

# When Replica Set is NOT initialized
$ mongo --quiet --port 27017 --username your-user --password your-pass --eval 'rs.status().ok'
0
```

This command works nicely on both primary and secondary nodes.

For more information, check:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/#response

Comment: rs.status().ok will return 0 also if user is unauthorised (i.e. you provided wrong credentials),  so its not very safe. on the other hand rs.status().code will return error code "13" in this scenario. rs.status().code is much safer if you want to check the init status.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `command()` function you're looking for:

Which gets a String argument.

Note: The `'getReplicaSetStatus'` command must be run on the **admin** database.

[http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#command(java.lang.String)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#command%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score -1):

There is another StackOverflow issue that appears to be the same question - See link below. 
the way to do this would be to get a list of databases that do exist - From the Java driver you could do something like this on a mongod server running on localhost

Mongo mongo = new Mongo( "127.0.0.1", 27017 );
List databaseNames = mongo.getDatabaseNames();

This is equivalent to the mongo shell "show dbs" command.

[Check if mongodb database exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049722/check-if-mongodb-database-exists)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure I follow this though; what will "getDatabaseNames()" return if the replicaset is and is not intialised? Could you expand a bit?

Comment: This does not even concern the question